# Strongly Dependent-type languages (running on windows)

Tags: solution-verification, type-theory, programming

What are the best dépendent-type programming languages to learn about type-theory ?

I heard about coq, agda, epigram and idris; are there any other ?

And most importantly: wich one of these can easily run on windows (and are light to install)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is off-topic here.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer.
But where can I ask my question then?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Stack Overflow, but you might ask it on Quora because it's kind of opinion based. Also, there are some relaxed chat rooms here for _soft-questions_.